# Property 'split' does not exist on type 'Int32Array'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

ERROR in src/app/account/phone-login/phone-login.component.ts(288,53): error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string | Int32Array'.
  Property 'split' does not exist on type 'Int32Array'.

I think this is really a strange problem, and the problem that comes up after the upgrade of the angular version

```
    let hash = (Md5.hashStr(this.account.password)).split('');
    hash[5] = this.account.password.charAt(0);
    hash[10] = this.account.password.charAt(1);
    hash[15] = this.account.password.charAt(2);
    let cryptoPwd = hash.join('');
```

Comment: so where is your code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int32Array `split` isn't a property or method of an Int32Array

Comment: I've added the code now。this mistake when I start the project use 'ng serve'

Comment: I've solved this problem.

The reason is that my MD5 conversion needs to be converted to a string

Comment: thank you very much @SterlingArcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let hash = ((Md5.hashStr(this.account.password)).toString()).split('');
hash[5] = this.account.password.charAt(0);
hash[10] = this.account.password.charAt(1);
hash[15] = this.account.password.charAt(2);
let cryptoPwd = hash.join('');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and  **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.